# Can a image tag in html z-index behind a css background image?

Tags: html, css, z-index, background-image, image

I have a css background image that I want in front of my img tag. The css background image has a z-index of 1, and the img tag has a z-index of 0. Am I allowed to put an img tag behind the css background with the z-index or will a css background always be behind an img tag regardless of it's z-index?

Comment: i think...if you set a image as background.you can't increase z-index.why don't you use two <img> tag

Comment: please an example of the code you talk about

Comment: @Anish - he means an element with background that contains and <img> inside. It can be done and it is valid just make sure you don't put it behind the <body> tag.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sure, a HTML element with a `background-image` and a higher `z-index` can overlay any other HTML element, in your case a simple `<img />` tag. But the `<img>` tag has not to be nested within the tag holding the background image.

This will work

```
<img src="../image.jpg" />
<div style="background: url(../image2.gif); z-index: 1">Content</div>
```

this not:

```
<div style="background: url(../image2.gif); z-index: 1">
    <img src="../imag.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works if you set position to either relative or absolute. Be sure to set it as it may just be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

use 2 divs with a background image or the divs and set each div / image the z-index

Answer (score 0):

Would be useful if you could show some code to understand what you want to do. 
If you only want to display an image in front of another, use 2 Containers like Div, or Span..

```
<div id="image1">
    <span id="image2"></span>
</div>
```